# PHP: Return the last json object

Tags: php, json

**Edit**

Thanks for all the input on this, I did find error in my question so modifying now. Sorry for that.

I am trying to figure out how to return the last object in the JSON string I have rendered. The two functions I am working with:

```
public function revision($return = false)
    {
        $id = $this->input->post('galleryID');
        $data = array('revision_count' => $this->revision->count_revision($id) );

        if($return){
            return json_encode($data);
        }
        else {
            echo json_encode($data);
        }
    }

public function last_revision()
        {
            $allRevisions = json_decode($this->revision(),true);
            return end($allRevisions);
        }
```

The issue is that end() returns error stating that 1st parameter should be array.

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: `edit_revision` doesn't return anything, it outputs the json encoded array `$data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to note here that `json_decode` returns an instance of stdClass by default. Try using `json_decode($jsonstring, true)` to return the JSON as a PHP associative array.

However, You haven't included what the `$this->revision()` method does. Could you possibly show that portion of the code, since that is the function you are getting a return value from?

Edit:

Alright, after we saw the right function in your code, here are a couple of things I would like to say:

- You have added a $return parameter to your `revision` method, but you aren't using it when you need to. You should change `$this->revision()` to `$this->revision(true)` in your `last_revision` method.
- If you're going to return data from the `revision()` method, there's not much of a point in `json_encode`ing it, just to `json_decode` the result. Just pass back the raw data array.
- Once you have changed both of these things, this should work:

  `$allRevisions = $this->revision(true); return end($allRevisions['revision_count']);`

Comment: Thanks, I have modified my question your comment helped discover a fault in my original question.

Comment: Thanks Colin - well explained and again sorry for the confusion in my orginal question.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the edit_function() to:

```
public function edit_revision($return = false)
{
  $galleryID  = $this->input->post('galleryID');
  $revisionID = $this->input->post('revisionID');

  $data = array('revision_images' => $this->revision->get($galleryID, $revisionID) );

  if($return)
    return json_encode($data);
  else
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

and then:

```
public function last_revision(true)
{
  $allRevisions = json_decode($this->revision());

   return end($allRevisions);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help on this. $allRevisions is not being returned as array, thus end() is throwing error.

Comment: See my last edit, just add the paramater `true` to the last_revision call.

Comment: thanks, that didn't do the trick, even if I set $return = true, I am still getting end() parameter 1 not an array.

Comment: this is the answer if you could modify your code to my updated question and pass  `true` to `revision()` -- Sorry for the mistake in code in original question `$this->revision(true)`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need convert that json output to an php array (json_decode() function), then you could get the last item with array_pop() function:
https://php.net/array_pop